# Date() constructor is rendering my page completely blank

Tags: reactjs

When I'm using the built-in Date() constructor it's rendering my page completely blank

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFdDS.png)

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1ijF.png)

```
import './ExpenseItem.css';

function ExpenseItem() {
 const expenseDate = new Date(2022, 1, 1)

  return (
      <div className='expense-item'>
          <div>{expenseDate}</div>
          <div className='expense-item__description'>
              <h2>Car Insurance</h2>
              <div className='expense-item__price'>$269.64</div>
          </div>
      </div>
  );
}

export default ExpenseItem;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are trying to render a `Date` as a React child and `Objects are not valid as a React child` (the reason behind your blank screen).

Change your code to be like:

```
const expenseDate = new Date(2022, 1, 1).toLocaleString();
```

In this way you will have a string instead, that is a valid React child.

Check the documentation on how to change your date-to-string format:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Answer (score 0):

** Because Date is an object and you cant render object as child**

// *toDateString()* will convert it into sting.

```
const expenseDate = new Date(2022, 1, 1).toDateString();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).